# How to find pairs of values greater than a certain cosine distance value?

Tags: python, cosine-similarity, pdist

I have an array:

```
[[ 0.32730174 -0.1436172  -0.3355202  -0.2982458 ]
 [ 0.50490916 -0.33826587  0.4315952   0.4850834 ]
 [-0.18594801 -0.06028342 -0.24817085 -0.41029227]
 [-0.22551994  0.47151482 -0.39798814 -0.14978702]
 [-0.3315491   0.05832376 -0.29526958  0.3786153 ]]
```

I have calculated its cosine distance with "pdist", `cosine_distance=1-pdist(array, metric='cosine')` and got the distance array:

```
[-0.14822659  0.51635946  0.09485546 -0.38855427 -0.82434624 -0.86407176
 -0.25101774  0.49793639 -0.07881047  0.41272145]
```

Now, I want to get only those pairs which's cosine distance is greater than 0.4 and less than 0.49. I have figured out the number of values which is greater than 0.4, by `number_points=len([1 for i in cosine_distance if i >= 0.4])`. But not able to get those pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in the description of the output for [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

> Y : ndarray
>
> Returns a condensed distance matrix Y. For each 
>   and (where ),where m is the number of original observations. The metric dist(u=X[i], v=X[j]) is computed and stored in entry ij.

The documentation also refers to [squareform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform) to make the distance vector a matrix again. The documentation explanation of the output array makes sense then. The `ij` position in the documentation will be the first and second index of the matrix created by the `squareform` operation. We can then get every distance regarding every point pair.

```
distance_matrix = squareform(cosine_distances_array)
points_to_keep = []

for (i in range(len(points)-1)):
    for (j in range(i+1, len(points))):
        if(distance_matrix[i,j] > 0.4):
            points_to_keep.push((points[i], points[j]))

print points_to_keep
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
number_points=len([1 for i in cosine_distance if i >= 0.4 and i <= 0.49])
```

If you need to keep track of which pair is in the range, use `enumerate`

```
number_points = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(cosine_distance) if i >= 0.4 and i <= 0.49]
```

This gives you a list with the indexes of the pairs which satisfies the conditions.